# Swift Update supported ios version

Tags: ios, swift, version, updates, target

I have project with iOS Deployment Target 8.0 but I want update to iOS  to support devices iOS 10 - 11.3

How to do it right

[image: im need to change Deployment Target and it will work?]
im need to change Deployment Target and it will work?
I can't find an answer to this problem

How can i do this? Thanks

Comment: What is going wrong when you try to change it to 11.3?

Comment: What's stopping you from updating to iOS 11.3? What does that have to do with your app's Deployment Target? Please explain what you have tried and what issues you are having.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to support iOS 11.3 you need to upgrade to Xcode 9.3.

That will include Swift 4.1 so you may get a lot of new warnings and errors in your Swift code depending on what version you are currently using.

Your project's Deployment Target has nothing to do with any of this. The Deployment Target defines the oldest version of iOS your app supports. If you keep your Deployment Target at iOS 8.0 (or anything earlier than the latest version of iOS) then you need to make sure that your code properly ensures that newer APIs are not used on older devices.

Comment: Re: the compile-time safety @rmaddy referenced, you may find [this post](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/checking-api-availability-with-swift/) useful.